# Auto id from table to text box id

Tags: ms-access

I have code like bellow that i want it get id in table departure to text box id name txtid to create next new id.But it don't return value that i need.

```
 Private Sub btnNew_Click()
  Call OpenControl(Me)
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim rc As New ADODB.Connection
    btnSave.Enabled = True
    Dim i As Integer
    With rs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open "SELECT DepID FROM tbDeparture", rc

            If (.RecordCount <= 0) Then
                i = 1
            Else
                    i = .Fields(0)
                        Do Until .EOF
                            .MoveNext
                        If .EOF Then
                            i = i + 1
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop
                End If
                 txtID = i
                 .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add one to the current max id you can use this although setting your ID field as an `autonumber` would be a better choice.

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click()
  Call OpenControl(Me)
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim rc As New ADODB.Connection

  btnSave.Enabled = True
  Dim i As Integer
  With rs
     .CursorLocation = adUseClient
     .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
     .LockType = adLockOptimistic
     .Open "SELECT max(DepID) FROM tbDeparture", rc
         If (.RecordCount <= 0) Then
            i = 1
         Else
             i = .Fields(0) + 1
         End If
         txtID = i
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```